# Escaping quotes in jinja2 for XPath

Tags: python, xpath, jinja2

The following line of code gives me problems:

```
{% if xml.findall('count("routes/route//process")') > 0 %}
```

I get this error message:

```
...
{% if xml.findall('count("routes/route//process")') > 0 %}
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 390, in findall
return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
KeyError: '('
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jinja2. `ElementTree` doesn't support the XPath expression you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElementTree has only [limited support for XPath expressions](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm). `count()` is *not* supported.

You'd have to switch to the [lxml library](http://lxml.de/); a ElementTree-compatible implementation that supports all of XPath 1.0.

Alternatively, test how many elements are returned directly:

```
{% if xml.findall('routes/route//process') %}
```

as a non-empty result list is true-thy in a boolean context.